# ns2 installation: Makefile:569: recipe for target 'tclsh.exe' failed

Tags: cygwin

I followed the instructions given by [www.soc.napier.ac.uk/~bill/ns_installation.doc](http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/~bill/ns_installation.doc) to install NS network simulator ns-2.35 on Cygwin. As the manual says I made sure all the following components are installed:

Automake

Make

Patch

Perl

X86 libraries

Window Maker

All GCC components

Nano Text editor (Optional… If you are not used to VI or other UNIX editors)

Xgraph (optional, but needed for test suites)

But, when I try to run ./install in ns-allinone to start installation, I get the following errors:
**-Package gcc4 not present on your system**
[image]
I didn't find a package with this name in Cygwin install window.
**-Package gcc4-g++ is not present on your system**
[image]
I think it should be OK to continue install without these packages as I installed gcc components completely, though I didn't find gcc4 in Cygwin repositories.
Finally, a message says "make failed".  The error says,

> "Makefile:569: recipe for target 'tclsh.exe' failed"

[image]
After installation, I cannot run ns or nam, showing the installation is incomplete. How can I solve the final error on building *tclsh* make failure

Comment: [so] duplicate: [No gcc4 in Cygwin's package list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21105574)

Comment: Have you read my comment above yet? It tells you exactly **why** it is failing and **how** to fix it.

Comment: @DavidPostill I read it, but I couldn't fix it using the page you linked. It mostly deals with missing packages, but my problem is mostly with building tclsh.exe as shown in the question, because other errors e.g. gcc4,gcc4-g++,etc., IMO, can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

tclsh shell is already available in cygwin, see
https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/tcl/tcl-8.5.18-1

as link it has by default no extension
/usr/bin/tclsh -> tclsh8.5.exe

If the software you are building is looking for "tclsh.exe"
just make a link like
/usr/local/bin/tclsh.exe -> /usr/bin/tclsh8.5.exe

or teach it to look for "tclsh"

Comment: It tries to build tclsh.exe as the error says and fails

Comment: I still got the error when I had it installed, so I uninstalled tclsh.exe and still got the same error, "Recipe for target tclsh.exe failed".

Comment: I made link as you said, but it didn't work.